# Managing complex data structure with React State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The client sends a message to the server

```js
    const sendMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const payload = {
            date: new Date().toISOString(),
            message: inputBuffer,
        }
        
        if (inputBuffer && inputBuffer.trim() !== '')
            socket.emit("sendMessage", payload);
        
        setInputBuffer("");
    }
```

The server receives the message and adds on the socket id and emits it to admins

```js
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        console.log("CONNECTION");
        socket.on("sendMessage", (args) => {
            args["socket_id"] = socket.id;
            adminNS.to("adminRoom").emit("clientMessage", args)
        })
    });
```

The object being emitted now looks like

```json
{
  date: '2023-08-08T19:32:11.999Z',
  message: 'abc',
  socket_id: 'G6e2gUJ5ExZzTaIlAAEP'
}
```

The Admin panel on the client listens for this

```js
    useEffect(() => {

        socketRef.current = io("/admin", {
            autoConnect: false,
            auth: {
                token: token
            }
        });
        socketRef.current.connect();

        socketRef.current.on("clientMessage", args => {
            setChats(chats => {
                const client = args.socket_id;
                let currentObj = chats;
                if (!currentObj[client]) {
                    currentObj[client] = [];
                    currentObj[client].messages = [];
                }
                    let newMessages = [];
                    newMessages.messages = currentObj[client].messages;
                    newMessages.messages.push(args.message);
                    currentObj[client] = newMessages;
                    return [currentObj];
            });
        })

        return () => {
            socketRef.current.removeEventListener("clientMessage");
        }

    }, [])
```

My setChats call currently outlines how I want the object to look
This setter is appending `args.message` into each messages array at `chats[args.socket_id]` every update

```json
[
G6e2gUJ5ExZzTaIlAAEP: {
  messages: [
               "User1Message here", "SecondMessage"
            ]
},

socket_id2: {
  message: [
               "User2Message here"
           ]
}
]
```

The problem is (I think), the setChat callback function is not "pure" and as such isn't working.

Once I have this achieved this data structure I can just iterate through the keys and their associated messages / array, and the end goal is to have many chat windows with the different client chats.

My question is, how can I form a "complex" object structure like this? Maybe I'm overcomplicating the matter and should have seperate state variables and associate them iteratively via a loop in the return portion of the component, but a key - toManyValues relationship seems like the most straight forward.

I have asked around and redux has been mentioned as a solution, or react query. But can this really not be achieved natively? I'd like to know what I'm missing here

Comment: (And oddly; what is `currentObj[client] = []; currentObj[client].messages = [];` supposed to **mean**? I'm not sure hanging arbitrary properties on an array is a safe approach.

Comment: @DaveNewton initializing arrays, or so I thought

Comment: But you set the property to an empty array, then set the property `messages` **on that array**, also to an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating `chats`, don't do that -

```js
socketRef.current.on("clientMessage", args => {
    setChats(chats => {
        const client = args.socket_id;
        return {
            ...chats,
            [client]: {
                ...(chats?.[client] ?? {}),
                messages: [
                    ...(chats?.[client]?.messages ?? []),
                    args.message,
                ],
            },
        }
     })
})
```

A bit of a nightmare? That's why projects like ImmutableJS and others exist.

---

Another recommendation would be to flatten your state. `useState` is cheap -

```
type ClientId = number

type Message = string

type Client = {
    id: ClientId
    name: string
}

const [clients, setClients] = useState<Map<ClientId, Client>>(() => new Map())

const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Map<ClientId, Array<Message>>>(() => new Map())
```

```js
socketRef.current.on("clientMessage", args => {
    setMessages(msgs => {
        const client = args.socket_id
        return new Map(msgs).set(
            client,
            (next.get(client) ?? [])
                .concat([args.message])
        )
    })
})
```

Without TypeScript -

```js
const [clients, setClients] = useState(() => new Map())

const [messages, setMessages] = useState(() => new Map())
```

```js
socketRef.current.on("clientMessage", args => {
    setMessages(msgs => {
        const client = args.socket_id
        return new Map(msgs).set(
            client,
            (next.get(client) ?? [])
                .concat([args.message])
        )
    })
})
```

Comment: Great, I wasn't aware of all those question mark operators. I'm also not using TypeScript but it seems very beneficial for this. Thanks for the top solution though. And a question for you, if I take all the logic out of the setChats callback and just return the `currentObj` is it still mutating chats?

Comment: the typescript is optional, i included it just to communicate the "shape" of the state more explicitly. you can use the bottom solution by removing all `type ...` statements and anything between `<...>`

Comment: `currentObj` *is* `chats`. if you return `currentObj` (which is `chats`) that means the state should not change, which is perfectly fine if you're doing a conditional state update. if you mutate `currentObj` it is still equal to `chats` because.. it *is* `chats`, so react will not detect a change _and_ you broke the state for the current render. mutations are things like `currentObj[key]=value` or `currentObj.push(newValue)` or `x++`.

Comment: btw i'm curious why you chose `let currentObj` instead of `const currentObj`? `const` doesn't prevent mutation, it only prevents reassignment. `const x = []; x.push(1);` is allowed, whereas `const x = []; x = [1];` is disallowed.

Comment: I didn't realise in javascript I was assigning by memory reference. I thought I was making a copy, so that makese sense now. Also you're right, I thought by using const I would be making the object immutable, which isn't the case